# Selecting total number of orders with an Inner Join

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: `tblOrders` and `tblItems`. Some users have 1 or more rows in `tblItems` which are each assigned a `fileID`. What I require is for the following code to count only orders where the user has 1 or more rows in `tblItems` for the selected date, which is why I check for `fileID > 0`.

However, this code returns a lesser count than it should:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalStalls 
FROM tblOrders
INNER JOIN tblItems ON tblOrders.accountID = tblItems.accountID 
                    AND tblItems.fileID > 0 
                    AND tblOrders.saleDate = @saleDate
WHERE tblOrders.saleDate = @saleDate 
GROUP BY tblorders.orderID
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You say you want to select orders, but your query selects counts, and that is confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited that now. I require the count of the number of rows. I wish to count every row it tblOrders where the user has also one or more columns in tblItems for the same date. EG: tblOrders has 3 orders in it. for 2 of those orders, 1 or more rows exist in tblItems. Therefore the count will be '2' as there are no rows in tblItems for the 3rd order.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS totalStalls 
FROM tblOrders
INNER JOIN tblItems ON tblOrders.accountID = tblItems.accountID 
WHERE tblOrders.saleDate = @saleDate
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I've tried this and it's giving me the same result as what I tried above. It counts 5 rows when it should be around 35 or more.

Comment: Please, add some data examples, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: I think, the problem is in the group by clause

Comment: How do I add data example? Do I have to edit the original question? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you will have to edit your post adding more information.

Comment: Some Rows from each table for example, and the output you expect.

Comment: I've tried both but the result is 2 more than my expected result. What I think is happening is that it is counting rows in tblItems which don't match the saledate for some reason.

Comment: We cannot help if you don't show some data example.

Comment: I've added a solution.. I didn't realise I had this code. Let me know what you think, because it works but I don't know why! I really appreciate your help though. I've learned a lot from trying to figure this out.

Comment: We can't figure out why the code is working because we don't have some data example but, what is important is you learned something as you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalStalls 
FROM tblOrders O

Where (select count(*) from tblItems I 
       where I.accountID = O.accountID and O.saleDate = @saleDate)
> 0
```

This should give you the count of Orders where the count of Items is greater than zero where the order sale date = @saleDate.

Comment: Thanks.  This is giving me:  syntax error near the keyword 'Where'

Comment: sorry, my mistake. No syntax error but result is still not quite right so i'm just trying to work out exactly what it's doing. I will post data when I figure out how to.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in some code that had previously been written for me and it works. Not entirely sure what the difference is from the suggestions on here?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount 
FROM tblOrders
WHERE saleDate = @saleDate AND
((SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM tblItems
WHERE (accountID = tblOrders.accountID) AND (saleDate = @saleDate)) > 0)
```